# How to refactor Methods with same structure, different classes (Java)

Tags: java, generics, refactoring, abstract, fileinputstream

What is the best way to refactor methods that have the same logic but use different classes (In Java)? Let's say

```
Method1(FileInputStream obj, OutputStream o){
  //stuff
  while(something){
    //---
    //some code
    //---
    obj.read();
    //---
    //some code
    //---
    o.write(..);
    //code
  }
  //code
}
```

and then I have

```
Method2(InputStreamReader obj, OutputStreamWriter os){
  //stuff
  while(something){
    //---
    //some code
    //---
    obj.read(..);
    //---
    //some code
    //---
    os.write();
    //code
  }
  //code
}
```

1 method deals with binary files and another deals with text. Ideally what I would want is to have a Read-Process-Write and hide away all of the specific information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use the correct interfaces:

```
void method2(Reader obj, Writer os){
   // code...   
}
```

Then use it like this for `InputStreams`

```
method2(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream), new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream));
```

**Why is this better?**

This is better because you are abstracting out the way the method works. You are saying you don't care what the implementation is, as long as it conforms to a `Reader` or `Writer`. Therefore, it is the responsibility of the user to change an `InputStream` to a `Reader`. *Not yours*. If there is an exception being thrown in that, then you **DON'T** need to catch it. It is thrown in client code. This is an important note.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read and write the same things so they don't have anything in common except the names.  The only way to make them common is to write binary and text as binary i.e. its all turned to binary in the end anyway.